# Calculating a value based on the word count of a textarea using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the need to calculate a price based on the number of words in a textarea. I will do my best to explain:

```
Flat fee = $35
Per prompt fee = $10
Per word fee = $.50 (after 30 words)
```

So I have the following textarea:

```
<textarea rows="10" class="form-control" name="voice-prompt-1" id="voice-prompt-1" placeholder="Type or paste your prompt here."></textarea>
<p>You have <span class="wordcount">0</span> words.</p>
```

And the following JS:

```
var perWord = '.50';
var flatFee = '35.00'
var promptPrice = '10.00';

function wordCount( val ){
    return {
        words : val.match(/\S+/g).length
    }
}

var div = $('span.wordcount');

jQuery('textarea#voice-prompt-1').on('input', function($) {

  var count = wordCount( this.value );

  div.html(count.words);

  additionalFees = perWord*count.words;

  total = parseFloat(flatFee) + parseFloat(promptPrice) + parseFloat(additionalFees);

  $('span.total').html(parseFloat(total.toString()).toFixed(2));

  console.log(total);

});
```

My question is how do I get the `perWord` value to calculate only after 30 words is entered?

Comment: `additionalFees = perWord * Math.max( 0, (count.words-30) );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to first check that you have at least 30 words then, subtract 30 form the word count to get additiona fees.

```
if (count.words > 30) {
  additionalFees = perWord * (count.words - 30);
}
```